How to pull all blocks from the genesis block to the local?
Now I need to do traceability business, I need pull all blocks from the genesis block to the local. May I ask if I need to build a validator node? If so, what params should I add?
right now I reserved 12T space, is this size enough space?

If you want to pull all blocks, you can use the getBlocks RPC endpoint, and go through every possible slot value from genesis to now. A validator node could help if you want to start logging blocks as they happen starting now, but it won't help with old blocks.
More information about the endpoint at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getblocks
